# Spies must be created in a before function or a spec

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am using jasmine.version "2.2.0". I am getting "**Spies must be created in a before function or a spec**" on my very basic test. 
What can be wrong? Please see code below;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <img src="../Content/jasmine/jasmine_favicon.png" />
    <link href="../Content/jasmine/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jasmine/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jasmine/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jasmine/boot.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script id="myRealCodeBase" type="text/javascript">
        var objectUnderTest = {
            someFunction: function (arg1, arg2) {
                var result = arg1 + arg2;
                return result;
            }
        };
    </script>
    <script id="testScripts" type="text/javascript">
        spyOn(objectUnderTest, 'someFunction');
        //Call the method with specific arguments
        objectUnderTest.someFunction('param1', 'param2');
        //Get the arguments for the first call of the function
        var callArgs = objectUnderTest.someFunction.call.argsFor(0);
        console.log(callArgs);
        //displays ['param1','param2']
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Standalone_Distribution) and try to move your test code inside a spec (`it` block)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you are not creating a test (spec) or using a before function, so that must be the problem.

You should wrap your tests in suites and specs, as they are called in jasmine, like this:

```
describe('A simple test', function () {
    beforeEach() {
        // callthrough is used to call the actual function, and not just mocking the call
        spyOn(objectUnderTest, 'someFunction').and.callThrough();
    };

    it('should add two numbers', function () {
        var sum = objectUnderTest.someFunction(1, 2);
        expect(sum).toEqual(3);
        expect(objectUnderTest.someFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

That is a simple test using jasmine. It is very simple, but it needs some structure to work. It is a very powerful framework, and once you get the hang of it, it is pretty simple and fun to write tests =)

Answer (score 1):

You're tests should be wrapped in a describe and an it block.

```
describe("A suite", function() {
  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```